# current page menu item style for wordpress.org page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, custom-wordpress-pages

I know this question has been asked before but all the resources I found didn't actually help me.

I have a normal website in wordpress.org (hosted in my server). home-about (that's the menu indicating each page's content). 
For some reason "home" is always selected no matter what page I'm on.

My menu items are something like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-1572">

<li id="menu-item-1715" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-1715">
```

Even if I go to Appearance > Edit CSS in my wordpress dashboard I can add any css I want but ..
can you please tell me how can I write for each page which menu item has an "is-selected" class?

If this was a normal static website I would go to each html page and then I would write for each menu item the proper class.

Example :

If home page:

```
<li id="menu-item-1572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object is-selected">HOME</li>

<li id="menu-item-1715" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object">ABOUT</li>
```

If about page:

```
<li id="menu-item-1572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object">HOME</li>

<li id="menu-item-1715" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object is-selected">ABOUT</li>
```

Now that I can't edit each html page on wordpress then can you give me directions on what to do?

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: @over-engineer big-brother-wpcom